# JavaScript this referring to global object in strict mode

Tags: javascript, this

I was learning `this` in JavaScript and according to my understanding inside strict mode `this` should be undefined but when I try this

```
"use strict";


function demo () {
    // Here this is Undefined in strict mode
    console.log(this);
}

//Here this refers to the Global Object
console.log(this);

demo();
```

As mentioned in the comment, console still prints the Window Object except when I call the demo() object. Why is that so?

Comment: This seems to be your solution [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#function_context)

Answer (score 2):

ECMA2015 (ES6) specified that global environment records supply a `this` value:

> 8.1.1.4.8 HasThisBinding ()
> Global Environment Records always provide a this binding whose value is the associated global object.

By ECMA2018,this was modified slightly - from table 17 in section 8.1.1.4 Global Environment Records of this edition:

> Table 17: Additional Fields of Global Environment Records
> ...
> **Field Name**: [[GlobalThisValue]]
> **Value**: Object
> **Meaning**: Object The value returned by **`this`** in global scope. Hosts may provide any ECMAScript Object Value.

However typical host environments still set the global `this` value to the global object and I assume will continue to do so.

While strict mode does provide that the [`this` value in an function called simply and directly to be `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode/Transitioning_to_strict_mode), it does not suppress the creation of a binding for `this` in the global environment record which will be seen as the `this` value in global, file-level code.